# Cordova Paypal Plugin payment success but not reflected on paypal

Tags: cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins

here fighting with paypal plugin.

After more than a day, i actually can send the payment now and i have a positive response

```
payment success: {
"response": {
    "state": "approved",
    "id": "PAY-6PU626847B294842SKPEWXHY",
    "create_time": "2014-07-18T18:46:55Z",
    "intent": "sale"
},
"client": {
    "platform": "Android",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "2.5.6",
    "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK",
    "environment": "mock"
},
"response_type": "payment"
}
```

but i went to the sandbox notifications on the [developers paypal website](https://developer.paypal.com/), it doesn't show anything.
Just in case, i went to [sandbox paypal website](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com) to check if the client made a pay or the business received one, there is nothing.

Is there any step that i'm jumping?

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was pretty silly, and pretty easy answer.

The environment is in mock = PayPalEnvrionmentNoNetwork

I just set PayPalEnvironmentSandbox and that's all

```
PayPalMobile.prepareToRender("PayPalEnvironmentSandbox", app.configuration(), app.onPrepareRender);
```

Comment: Can you tell me which plugin have you used? I'm trying to use paypal on my cordova app with no result.Can you help me?

Comment: I'm using this plugin but every time I try to do the payment I get the errors mentioned in this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919986/paypal-payment-with-cordova-plugin.
This error related to `ActivityNotFoundException`. So have you done any change while installing the `Paypal-Cordova plugin`?

Comment: No idea. By client request, i've change the paypal modulo to stripe, and it's so much easy to implement.
https://stripe.com/
https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Stripe
good luck