# paypal payment with cordova plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, paypal

I'm trying to use `paypal` payment in my `cordova` application.
For that I used this [Paypal cordova plugin](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin). I followed all the instructions mentioned there, but I get these errors:

```
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112): Uncaught exception from plugin
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.hello/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.startActivityForResult(CordovaActivity.java:748)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at com.paypal.cordova.sdk.PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.renderSinglePaymentUI(PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.java:226)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at com.paypal.cordova.sdk.PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.execute(PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.java:54)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:84)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:147)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-13 05:18:06.650: E/PluginManager(2112):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Can any one help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: can you open this issue on our github with details what version of the library are you using and exact intsturctions you have tried https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin/issues . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem.
In the process of `installation of the plugin` there was a problem.
So that I referenced the file `cdv-plugin-paypal-mobile-sdk.js` in the `paymnt.html` page and it works now.